# GnssStatus.CallBack onSatelliteStatusChanged() not working

Tags: android, gps, android-navigation, android-gps, satellite-navigation

I am developing an application that I want to learn about the count of gps satellites. I am using the "onSatelliteStatusChanged" method for this, but it does not work. The piece of code that I use below that you see.

**Code**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            gnssStatusCallBack = new GnssStatus.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSatelliteStatusChanged(GnssStatus status) {

                        satelliteCount = status.getSatelliteCount();
                }
            };
            locManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gnssStatusCallBack);
 } else {
      locManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
 }
}
```

Note: I tested it outside.

Comment: Hello, Yes I found the solution. The problem stems from the fact that the super method is not called. Call the super.onSatelliteStatusChanged (status) inside onSatelliteStatusChanged method.

Comment: Does someone know how many the number should be to say Good GPS Availability? and also Bad GPS Availability? I need it to distinguish between indoor and outdoor location!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Overview (request location updates to receive them):

Without explicitly asking for location updates, your device may not be seeking this information.  The following worked for me where member `mGnssStatusCallback` is your [GnssStatus.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssStatus.Callback.html) and the Activity (or some other class) implements [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html); here this activity implements it and I pass `this` as the final parameter to `requestLocationUpdates` and `removeUpdates`.  The `30000` indicates that we're requesting updates every 30 seconds (30000 *milli*seconds), with `0` indicating that we only want an update if the device has moved > 0 meters.

---

**You probably need to figure out what providers are available, *etc*.

see [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).**

---

### Example

```
public class GnssActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    GnssStatus.Callback mGnssStatusCallback;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mLocationManager = 
                (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mGnssStatusCallback = new GnssStatus.Callback() {
            // TODO: add your code here!
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLocationManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(mGnssStatusCallback);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, this
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        mLocationManager.unregisterGnssStatusCallback(
                mGnssStatusCallback
        );
        super.onStop()
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
            Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    ⋮
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note also that the

> GnssStatus Callback

would never get called if the provider is not set to `GPS_PROVIDER`

```
locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, this);
```

A common mistake is to set the provider to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`